# linking array values in an object to an array in a nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do I take every string value in the imageKeys array and use it to construct a url in the images array in the nested object imageList, without mutating the object?

```
     const myInitialStateFromParent = {
       imageKeys: ['name1', 'name2'],
       itemType: "something",
       itemName: "something else",
       ImageList:{
        images: [], 
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        maxImages: 2
       }
     }
```

for each key in imageKeys I want to add a new object in the empty images array.
eg:

```
{url: baseUrl + '/' + 'name1'},
{url: baseUrl + '/' + 'name2'}
```

I want to keep everything else in the entire object the same. This is in a React child function component, useEffect(() => {}, [imageKeys]).

I tried something like,

```
  for (const k of myInitialStateFromParent.imageKeys) {
      var img = {url: `baseUrl${k}`}
      [...myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images, img] // copy the images, insert new one
  }
```

But I'm getting an error about spread only working with the last formal parameter.

Comment: You're not assigning the spread array to anything so it is being read as a destructuring assignment. Add an assignment and your code works. `myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images = [...myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images, img];`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myInitialStateFromParent = {
  imageKeys: ['name1', 'name2'],
  itemType: "something",
  itemName: "something else",
  ImageList:{
   images: [], 
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   maxImages: 2
  }
}

const baseUrl = 'dummyUrl';

function mapUrls(object) {
  const { imageKeys, ImageList }  = object;
  const newImagesList = {
    ...ImageList,
    images: imageKeys.map((string) => ({ url: `${baseUrl}/${string}`}))
  };
  
  return {
    ...object,
    ImageList: newImagesList
  }
}

console.log(mapUrls(myInitialStateFromParent))
```

Comment: thanks but I need the urls in the images array off ImageList, not in imageKeys. image keys should stay as they are.  ImageList {images: [{url: 'xdx'}]}

Comment: Fixed the code.

Comment: Wait, I must have not explained it clearly. My apologies. What I'm saying is the object should look like this after: 

```
const myInitialStateFromParent = {
  imageKeys: ['name1', 'name2'],
  itemType: "something",
  itemName: "something else",
  ImageList:{
   images: [{"url": "dummyUrl/name1"},
  {"url": "dummyUrl/name2"}], 
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
   maxImages: 2
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how reply with code here, sorry. The objects with the dummy urls you created should be in the images array toward the bottom - not in imagekeys. Image keys should stay as they are.

Comment: @MattoMK Fixed again. I hope thats what you need)

Comment: damn. I didn't realize you could do it like that. the key takeaway for me here is pulling out what you need by going const {what, i, want } = source. I was over-thinking it. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you just need to push values to your images array:

Easy way:

```
myInitialStateFromParent.imageKeys.forEach((k) => {
  myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images.push({ url: `baseUrl${k}` });
});
```

You're not assigning values in your code, in order to use your code and have results you have to change it, and assign the new values to that array.

Hard way:

```
for (const k of myInitialStateFromParent.imageKeys) {
  const img = { url: `baseUrl${k}` };
  myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images = [
    ...myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images,
    img,
  ];
  // or 
  // myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images = myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images.concat(img);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but isn't pushing an object onto an array considered mutating the object? For react, don't you need to map and return a new object entirely?

Comment: I think that principle is related to Redux, but it depends on the case you're updateding the array. If you're using that object only in that component, it won't affect your software. (I would probably fetch those info directly in the child component)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```js
const myInitialStateFromParent = {
       imageKeys: ['name1', 'name2'],
       itemType: "something",
       itemName: "something else",
       ImageList:{
        images: [], 
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        maxImages: 2
       }
     }
myInitialStateFromParent.imageKeys.forEach(key=>{
  return myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images.push({url: 'baseURL'+key})
})

console.log(myInitialStateFromParent.ImageList.images)
```